# Loop in custom Datasource for highlighting range of rows Mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to implement a range selection in angular in a mat-table. i've already done it with a simple array for the datasource but in my project, the datasource is a custom one from a Datasource class.

Here is the range selection for a simple datasource :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xljvp4

you need to select the first row and then press the shift key and select the second one to select the all range of rows.

The problem is in my project i have this datasource :

Datasource :

```
    private product = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);
    private loadingProduct = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public loading$ = this.loadingProduct.asObservable();

    constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) { }

    /**
     * This method will need to return an Observable that emits the lessons data, but we don't want to expose the internal subject lessonsSubject directly.

        Exposing the subject would mean yielding control of when and what data gets emitted by the data source, and we want to avoid that. We want to ensure that only this class can emit values for the lessons data.

        So we are also going to return an Observable derived from lessonsSubject using the asObservable() method. This gives the data table (or any other subscriber) the ability to subscribe to the lessons data observable, without being able to emit values for that same observable.
     * @param collectionViewer 
     */
    connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Product[]> {

        return this.product.asObservable();
    }
    /**
     * This method is called once by the data table at component destruction time. In this method, we are going to complete any observables that we have created internally in this class, in order to avoid memory leaks.

        We are going to complete both the lessonsSubject and the loadingSubject, which are then going to trigger the completion of any derived observables. 
     * @param collectionViewer 
     */
    disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
        this.product.complete();
        this.loadingProduct.complete();
    }

    loadProduct(filter: string[] = [], column: string = 'id',
        sortDirection: string = 'asc', pageIndex: number = 0, pageSize: number = 100) {
        this.loadingProduct.next(true);

        this.productsService.getAll(filter, sortDirection,
            pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(
                catchError(() => of([])),
                finalize(() => this.loadingProduct.next(false))
            )
            .subscribe(products => this.product.next(products));
    }
}
```

And i would like to be able to do a foreach on all data in the datasource like in the stackblitz exemple :

```
ELEMENT_DATA.forEach((item,index) => {
          if(index >= this.indexSelected && index <= alldata){
            item.isSelected = true;
            this.productsArray.push(item);
          }else{
            item.isSelected = false;
          }
        })
```

Is there a way to loop in all the data in a custom Datasource ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your template, send the data to the handler:

```
(click)="toggleSelected(row, $event, i, dataSource.data)"
```

Then you can easily loop over the data.

See my updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dh9sa5

Comment: Thanks for your response, unforunatly i get this message :
`
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
  `